# JavaScript - I'm reading a json file and trying to read the values of a certain key

Tags: javascript, json

So here is my javascript code, I am looping over my json file which is below and I want to check the 'bought_together' values that are nested under 'related' but I can't seem to do it with my code I've got so far. I'm using 'document.body.innerHTML = 'hello';' so I can see if my if statement works or not so I can execute what I want to do. Hope this makes sense to you if it doesn't just let me know.

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.products, function(key, val) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
        var obj = data.products[i];
        if (obj.related == 'bought_together') {
          document.body.innerHTML = 'hello';
        }
      }

    });
  })
})
```

Here is a snippet of my json file so you can have an idea of what I'm working with.

```
{
  "products": [{
    "asin": "B0001MQ60A",
    "title": "KEEN Men's Newport H2 Sandal",
    "imUrl": "http://ecx.images- 
    amazon.com / images / I / 41 pRaO7fFSL._SX395_.jpg ",
    "related": {
      "also_bought": ["B000MN8OR6"],
      "also_viewed": ["B0000DYKET", "B0035FE60M", "B008KI85R4", "B000MQWVA4",
        "B003Z4KHXS", "B00GUBOCGQ",
        "B003O2SLXY", "B0017KSRMA", "B003O2SBKM", "B00DSN637U", "B000HDJ8IK", "B00E0J3HVG", "B003Z4KGZW",
        "B005HO2CYG", "B003H4QFVY", "B0017LB2VC", "B002R8JPTK", "B008KI84SE", "B005DJDL9A", "B003TU14OE",
        "B00E0J3HTI", "B000EDTVYY", "B003Z4JOJG", "B00DSN638E", "B00E0J3HVQ", "B008KI88JY", "B00EZIRE20",
        "B0095RGEH2", "B00CEX6MSU", "B000B84URK", "B003O2SPMG", "B002KKCWP4", "B003O2SLXE", "B00JQHFV0M",
        "B008JE8V14", "B0055ATVDW", "B003Z4KLMA", "B008ZAY40Y", "B003H4QFV4", "B00DSN64BU", "B002KKCZLA",
        "B0055ATVV4", "B00HFY47JY", "B00DPHJUTW", "B008FWRJ6I", "B003Z4JUFO", "B00JFB4RL8", "B00HR1LTNM",
        "B005HMTPBG", "B00KCT84I4", "B00HXDITEG"
      ],
      "bought_together": ["B003O2SLXY", "B003H4QFVY", "B002R8JPTK", "B000EDTVYY"]
    },
    "salesRank": {
      "Shoes": 18
    },
    "categories": [
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Shoes & Accessories: International Shipping Available"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "K", "Keen"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Comfort Shoes"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Sandals"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Athletic", "Sport Sandals"]
    ]
  }]
}
```

Comment: [MCVE] please!!!

Comment: Have you used `'bought_together' in obj.related`?

Comment: Why are you iterating over the `products` with `$.each()` and then iterating again over the same `products` with a `for` loop for each item inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.related` doesn't contain a string, it contains an object -- so you don't want to check for the string "bought_together", you want to check whether the key with that name exists:

```js
// For demo, data is in a var instead of an ajax call:
var data = {
  "products": [{
    "asin": "B0001MQ60A",
    "title": "KEEN Men's Newport H2 Sandal",
    "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pRaO7fFSL._SX395_.jpg",
    "related": {
      "also_bought": ["B000MN8OR6"],
      "also_viewed": ["B0000DYKET", "B0035FE60M", "B008KI85R4", "B000MQWVA4",
        "B003Z4KHXS", "B00GUBOCGQ",
        "B003O2SLXY", "B0017KSRMA", "B003O2SBKM", "B00DSN637U", "B000HDJ8IK", "B00E0J3HVG", "B003Z4KGZW",
        "B005HO2CYG", "B003H4QFVY", "B0017LB2VC", "B002R8JPTK", "B008KI84SE", "B005DJDL9A", "B003TU14OE",
        "B00E0J3HTI", "B000EDTVYY", "B003Z4JOJG", "B00DSN638E", "B00E0J3HVQ", "B008KI88JY", "B00EZIRE20",
        "B0095RGEH2", "B00CEX6MSU", "B000B84URK", "B003O2SPMG", "B002KKCWP4", "B003O2SLXE", "B00JQHFV0M",
        "B008JE8V14", "B0055ATVDW", "B003Z4KLMA", "B008ZAY40Y", "B003H4QFV4", "B00DSN64BU", "B002KKCZLA",
        "B0055ATVV4", "B00HFY47JY", "B00DPHJUTW", "B008FWRJ6I", "B003Z4JUFO", "B00JFB4RL8", "B00HR1LTNM",
        "B005HMTPBG", "B00KCT84I4", "B00HXDITEG"
      ],
      "bought_together": ["B003O2SLXY", "B003H4QFVY", "B002R8JPTK", "B000EDTVYY"]
    },
    "salesRank": {
      "Shoes": 18
    },
    "categories": [
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Shoes & Accessories: International Shipping Available"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "K", "Keen"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Comfort Shoes"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Sandals"],
      ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Athletic", "Sport Sandals"]
    ]
  }]
}



// as noted in another answer, you can use $.each or a for loop, no need for both.
for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
  var obj = data.products[i];
  if (obj.related["bought_together"]) {
    console.log("found: ", obj.related["bought_together"]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `for` loop because you have already get throught your `$.each` loop

```
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
      $.each( data.products, function( key, val ) {
        if (Object.key(data.products.related).length) { // make sure the key related exist
            if (data.products.related['bought_together']) { 
               document.body.innerHTML = 'hello';
            }
        }
    });
    })})
```

If you want to use `for` loop, don't do it into `$.each`

```
...

    for (var i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
        var obj = data.products[i];

        if (obj.related['bought_together']) { // if doesn't exist return undefined
             document.body.innerHTML = 'hello';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`data.products[i].related` is an array and not a string so to check if it exists you could use

```
typeof data.products[i].related !== "undefined"
```

or if it always exists and you need to know if it contains any elements:

```
data.products[i].related.length>0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you want to check if the "bought_together" property exists and, if true, type "hello" in your document.

You can do this more easily, like this:

```js
var jsonText = '{ "products": ['+
'{'+
'"asin": "B0001MQ60A",'+
'"title": "KEEN Men\'s Newport H2 Sandal",'+
'"imUrl": "http://ecx.images- amazon.com/images/I/41pRaO7fFSL._SX395_.jpg",'+
'"related": {'+
'  "also_bought": ["B000MN8OR6"],'+
'  "also_viewed": ["B0000DYKET", "B0035FE60M", "B008KI85R4", "B000MQWVA4"],'+
'  "bought_together": ["B003O2SLXY", "B003H4QFVY", "B002R8JPTK", "B000EDTVYY"]'+
'},'+
'"salesRank": {"Shoes": 18},'+
'"categories": ['+
' ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Shoes & Accessories: International Shipping Available"],'+
' ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "K", "Keen"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Comfort Shoes"],'+
' ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Sandals"],'+
' ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Shoes", "Athletic", "Sport Sandals"]'+
']}'+
']}';

jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonText);

var found = jsonObj.products.find(product => product.related && !!product.related["bought_together"]);

if (found) {
 document.body.innerHTML = 'hello';
}
```